# Cannot open some tables in phpmyadmin

Tags: innodb, mysql-5.5, phpmyadmin

Recently i get backup of my database from host in that backup i get table in .ibd,.frm,.myd format .

I placed this files in

> xampp->mysql->data->test

. Now i can open the tables in php myadmin. Now i can open some tables .But some files i can not open . When clicked it showing `932 - Table 'table.name' doesn't exist in engine` . And also i noticed in the collection column it is showing in use

Why this happen . Please help to solve

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy frm and ibd files ONLY if the tablespace ID in idb file is the same as the tablespace ID in ibdata1, if it's not then the data will be corrupt and you will be missing tables.

When I had that problem I used this resource to recover files:

- [Recover InnoDB into MySQL](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/04/recover-innodb-mysql/)

You may also find these links useful:

- [Recover InnoDB from ibd File](http://www.chriscalender.com/recovering-an-innodb-table-from-only-an-ibd-file/)
- [Manually Importing InnoDB MySQL Table Files](http://www.hackaapl.com/manually-re-locating-importing-mysql-innodb-table-files-file_per_table/)